# In Ubuntu10.04 terminal: QtSdk-offline-linux-x86-v1.2.1.run:cannot excute this binary file

Tags: qt

I'm trying to set up a QT environment,So I downloaded the QtSdk-offline-linux-x86-v1.2.1.run
However, a problem comes.
I've tried the following steps:

root@linux-desktop:/usr# chmod u+x QtSdk-offline-linux-x86-v1.2.1.run

root@linux-desktop:/usr# ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86-v1.2.1.run

bash: ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86-v1.2.1.run：cannot excute binary file

I've updated the g++ already.

Who can tell me how to fix this?Help.
THanks!

Comment: what does `file QtSdk-offline-linux-x86-v1.2.1.run` says about that file?

Comment: here is the code:                                          root@linux-desktop:/usr# chmod u+x QtSdk-offline-linux-x86-v1.2.1.run                                                root@linux-desktop:/usr# ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86-v1.2.1.run                                                 bash: ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86-v1.2.1.run：无法执行二进制文件

Comment: please try the `file` command on that `.run` file. Maybe it's corrupt or you're running on a different architecture (not x86?)

Comment: here's the manpage: [file(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file)

Comment: You are right!THanks,I run this Ubuntu in a VirtualBox. I've just checked the systeminfo,actually,not x86...

Comment: Hello,dschlz! I wonder if there is something:               root@linux-desktop:/usr# uname -a
Linux linux-desktop 2.6.32-28-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 10 21:21:01 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
(above is in the virtualbox),my hostmachine is intel i5 64bits,I missed sth for the sake my poor knowledge of the architecture.sorry